# The distribution of number of reverse order pairs in a randomly permuted array

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

There is an array $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$ whose elements are pairwise distinct. We define a reverse order pair to be an ordered pair $(a_i,a_j)$ such that $i < j$ and $a_i > a_j$. Consider the total number of reverse order pairs $N$.

Assume the array is permuted uniformly and randomly, it is well known that $E[N] = \frac{n(n+1)}{4}$. What is the probability distribution of $N$?

Comment: Is $X$ the same thing as $N$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, sorry for my typo. I correct it. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a quick note on terminology: the standard term for a "reverse order pair" is an *inversion*. Knowing this makes it easier to search for the answer:

The generating function for the number of permutations with $k$ inversions is the $q$-factorial $[n]_q!$ as shown e.g. [here](https://www.tvhoang.com/articles/2021/03/inversion-stat-distribution-proof).